# From x-display-pixel-width in Emacs 23 to display-monitor-attributes-list in Emacs 24

Tags: emacs, emacs24, emacs23, dot-emacs

In Emacs 23, evaluating

```
(x-display-pixel-width)
```

yielded the width of the current window.

In Emacs 24 the same expression returns the combined width of all windows.

How does one return the width of just the main/current window while evaluating the related, but new and improved, function

```
(display-monitor-attributes-list)
```

?

Comment: `(window-width)` -- please note that this is `window`, *not* `frame`.  Do you need a more detailed example?  E.g., `(with-current-buffer (get-buffer ...`

Comment: I'm looking for pixel width, not character width. Also, I'm looking for a measure of the (main) monitor (I'm on OS X). This is for inclusion in .emacs, before the frame is set.

Comment: How about the manual at section *28.23 Coordinates and Windows*?:  http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Coordinates-and-Windows.html#Coordinates-and-Windows

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `display-monitor-attribute-list`:

> (display-monitor-attributes-list &optional DISPLAY)
>
> Return a list of physical monitor attributes on DISPLAY. Each element
>   of the list represents the attributes of each physical monitor.  The
>   first element corresponds to the primary monitor.
>
> Attributes for a physical monitor is represented as an alist of
>   attribute keys and values as follows:
>
> geometry -- Position and size in pixels in the form of
>          (X Y WIDTH HEIGHT)  workarea -- Position and size of the workarea in pixels in the
>          form of (X Y WIDTH HEIGHT)  mm-size  -- Width and height in millimeters in the form of
>          (WIDTH HEIGHT)  frames   -- List of frames dominated by the physical monitor  name (*) -- Name of the physical monitor as a string
>
> where X, Y, WIDTH, and HEIGHT are integers.  Keys labeled with (*) are
>   optional.
>
> A frame is dominated by a physical monitor when either the largest
>   area of the frame resides in the monitor, or the monitor is the
>   closest to the frame if the frame does not intersect any physical
>   monitors.  Every non-tip frame (including invisible one) in a
>   graphical display is dominated by exactly one physical monitor at a
>   time, though it can span multiple (or no) physical monitors. If
>   DISPLAY is omitted or nil, it defaults to the selected frame's
>   display.

For example, to find the width of the first monitor, you could use:

```
(nth 4 (assq 'geometry (car (display-monitor-attributes-list))))
```

Comment: When I try your example in emacs 24, I get `eval: Symbol's function definition is void: display-monitor-attributes-list`.